# How to install apk in platform tools adb?

Tags: apk

How to install apk by using adb in platform tools like this:

```
./adb install ~/facebook-android-sdk-3.0.2/bin/FBAndroid-2.1.apk
```

I am opening the adb in platform tools in android sdk but everytime the window displays process completed and does not enable editing. So how can I add the above line in adb?

Comment: Open console at first (cmd in windows) and launch adb with params (by entering string you mention) from there

Comment: this is mac os n i am using terminal but when opening adb it shows the 'process completed' and it is unable to write any command here. how can i give path in terminal hash?

Answer (score 0):

In your OS shell enter

```
adb install app.apk
```

as one line.

Do not use `./` as it reference file in current dir, while `adb` should be search for by system.